Getting same element while looping through DataItems with WinAppDriver using FindElementByAccessibilityId
I am very new to automation using WinAppDriver and facing a very strange issue when I am trying to find a particular row index.
This code works fine
 var dataItem7 = bidsGrid.FindElementByAccessibilityId("7");
var subDataItem7 = dataItem7.FindElementByAccessibilityId("XRef"); 
Here the items just stick to the 0th index data item
for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    var dataItem = bidsGrid.FindElementByAccessibilityId(i.ToString());
    var subDataItem = dataItem.FindElementByAccessibilityId("XRef");
}

